# Unable to download PDF file using playwright with js because it's open in preview mode in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, playwright, playwright-test

I am facing an issue where I am unable to download a PDF file because it opens in the preview mode in the Chrome browser
[i want to enable this option using playwright with JS so i can download directly without opening the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7cfL.png)

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
test.only('test', async () => {

    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        args: ['--disable-pdf-extension'],
      });
    
      const context = await browser.newContext({
        acceptDownloads: true, // Enable automatic download handling
      });

  // Navigate to the page containing the PDF link
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Email' }).fill('admin@gmail.com');
  await page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Email' }).press('Tab');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill('admin123');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').press('Enter');
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Qa testing Learning', exact: true }).click();
  await page.getByText('Subscribers').click();
  const pdfLink = page.getByRole('row', { name: 'pdf' }).getByRole('link');
  await pdfLink.click();

  await page.pause();
  
});
```

Comment: One of the ways that I handled this was using the src attribute of the locator to open the link in a new tab and download the page into pdf, this was to avoid switching frames in Chrome while automation
`let src = await page.locator("<download-locator-link>").getAttribute('src');
    await page.goto(src);
    await page.emulateMedia({ media: 'screen' });
    await page.pdf({ path: 'desired.pdf' });`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

1. Start waiting for download before clicking. Note no await.

   const downloadPromise = page.waitForEvent('download');
   await page.getByText('Download file').click();
   const download = await downloadPromise;
2. Wait for the download process to complete and save the downloaded file somewhere.

   await download.saveAs('/path/to/save/at/' + download.suggestedFilename());

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-download